# Google Geolocation on beforeSave

Tags: parse-platform

I'm trying to do Geolocation using Google Maps API on beforeSave event for Parse Cloud. The problem is httpRequest isn't triggered between the process.

Here's my code:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave('SearchList', function (request, response) {

    if ( ! request.object.isNew())
        response.success();

    var SearchList = Parse.Object.extend('SearchList');
    var query = new Parse.Query(SearchList);

    query.equalTo('Id', request.object.get('Id'));
    query.first({
        success: function (entry) {

            if (entry) {

                var address = request.object.get('Street1') + ', ' + request.object.get('Street2') + ', ' + request.object.get('Street3') + ', ' + request.object.get('Suburb') + ', ' + request.object.get('State') + ', ' + request.object.get('Postcode');

                for (var attr in request) {
                    entry.set(attr, request[attr]);
                }
                entry.set('Address', address);

                if (request.object.get('Type') === 'Bus') {

                    address = request.object.get('Street1') + ', ' + request.object.get('State');
                    console.log('Bus Address: ' + address);
                    Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
                        method: 'POST',
                        url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json',
                        params: {
                            address : address,
                            key: 'my-api-key'
                        },
                        success: function(httpResponse) {

                            var response = httpResponse.data;

                            if (response.status === 'OK') {
                                var langLat = response.results[0].geometry.location;
                                console.log(langLat);

                                entry.set('Location', new Parse.GeoPoint({ latitude: Number(langLat.latitude), longitude: Number(langLat.longitude) }));
                                entry.save();
                                response.error('Updated Existing Entry');
                             }

                        },
                        error: function(httpResponse) {
                            entry.set('Location', null);
                            entry.save();
                            response.error('Updated Existing Entry');
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    entry.set('Location', new Parse.GeoPoint({ latitude: Number(request.object.get('Latitude')), longitude: Number(request.object.get('Longitude')) }));
                    entry.save();
                    response.error('Updated Existing Entry');
                }

            } else {
                response.success();
            }

        },
        error: function (err) {
            response.error('Could not validate uniqueness for the Id object.');
        }
    });

});
```

So what my code does is during save, I checked the entry if it already existed in the database. If it exist I simple update its values and then return a `response.error` telling `parseObject.save` to not continue to save the data since it already existed, else I return a `response.success` telling `parseObject.save` to continue saving the data. So during this process there are some data who don't have lat-long values, so I have to check whether they have lat-long, if they don't I wanted to do a Geolocation query using the entry's address w/ Google Maps API to retrieve the lat-long values.

Any ideas on how I can execute Geolocation using Google Maps API during beforeSave?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you querying to find the object when it's new and therefore shouldn't exist in the data store? So, if it's not new, do nothing, and if it's new, find the existing item (which shouldn't exist) and only make the request if we find it. This seems illogical so you need to explain what you're doing in more detail

Comment: @Wain sorry, I didn't explain well what my code does.
So in this part, I checked if the new entry has already existed and if it does exist, I simply update the values and do a `response.error` which signals the `parseObject.save()` to not continue to save the object, else i return a `response.success` telling `parseObject.save()` to continue saving the new data. The reason why I wanted to do a Geolocation search is because I need to get a latlong points for the existing data, because some data don't include latlong so I have to implement a check whether they include a latlong values.

Answer (score 0):

When you call reaponse success or error you're signalling that the function is complete, so anything after that isn't guaranteed to complete, especially if it's asynchronous.

You should make the asynchronous request and update the passed object and then return success to save it.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I have to implement a Parse.Promise request and chain the request instead. It now works properly.